# How to diagnose brown spots on dogwood leaves

Tags: trees, diseases

We have a pink dogwood that was planted two years ago. Its leaves all have brown spots, and some leaves are quite covered with brown. It is more pronounced this year than last year.

From research online I suspect dogwood anthracnose but am hopeful that it's something less serious like spot anthracnose or leaf blight.

I don't notice any symptoms other than the leaf spots/browning. No notable branch dieback, no water sprouts, etc.

Is it possible for me to narrow down the diagnosis on my own, or will I need a tree expert to come take a look?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you have a wet spring?

Comment: I don't think it was particularly wetter or drier than usual.